# What is the best way to format long chained methods?

Tags: formatting, chaining, method-chaining, code-readability

What is the best way to format code with chained methods?  Especially if it goes on for a long time?  If you have a chain of three or so, you can put it on one line, but it gets cumbersome after you have a lot and it makes debugging difficult.

FYI, I'm talking about this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Sometimes I write code like this (in Java):

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Taskdsr.class);
criteria=criteria.add(someRestriction);
criteria=criteria.add(someOtherRestriction);
criteria=criteria.setFetchMode(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

in place of:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Taskdsr.class).add(someRestriction).add(someOtherRestriction).setFetchMode(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format it across multiple lines:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Taskdsr.class)
                            .add(someRestriction)
                            .add(someOtherRestriction)
                            .setFetchMode(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```